# I am trying to use pandas after to installed it, but it still doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, module

So, when I was trying to install pandas I choose the option pip besides anaconda. Using prompt I just typed the codes in this sequence:

```
python --version | -m pip --version | py -m pip --version | -m pip install pandas
```

After this I typed the import in the cmd and I didn't  could use the pandas.

This is what a I did in my prompt:

```
C:\Users\CLIENTE>python --version
Python 3.9.1rc1

C:\Users\CLIENTE>python -m pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CLIENTE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\CLIENTE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\CLIENTE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main
  File "C:\Users\CLIENTE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils import _log
ImportError: cannot import name '_log' from 'pip._internal.utils' (C:\Users\CLIENTE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\__init__.py)

C:\Users\CLIENTE>py -m pip --version
pip 22.0.4 from C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3312.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)

C:\Users\CLIENTE>py -m pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Downloading pandas-1.4.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (10.5 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 10.5/10.5 MB 2.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting numpy>=1.18.5
  Downloading numpy-1.22.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (14.7 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 14.7/14.7 MB 2.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.8.1
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
Collecting pytz>=2020.1
  Using cached pytz-2022.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (503 kB)
Collecting six>=1.5
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Installing collected packages: pytz, six, numpy, python-dateutil, pandas
  WARNING: The script f2py.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\CLIENTE\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed numpy-1.22.3 pandas-1.4.2 python-dateutil-2.8.2 pytz-2022.1 six-1.16.0

C:\Users\CLIENTE>py -m pip install pandas --no-warn-script-location
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\cliente\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (1.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.1 in c:\users\cliente\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.18.5 in c:\users\cliente\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from pandas) (1.22.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in c:\users\cliente\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from pandas) (2022.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\cliente\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.1->pandas) (1.16.0)

C:\Users\CLIENTE>python
Python 3.9.1rc1 (tags/v3.9.1rc1:88db374, Nov 24 2020, 19:27:23) [MSC v.1928 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\CLIENTE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\pandas\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import is_numpy_dev as _is_numpy_dev
  File "C:\Users\CLIENTE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import (
  File "C:\Users\CLIENTE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\pandas\compat\numpy\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pandas.util.version import Version
  File "C:\Users\CLIENTE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\pandas\util\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.util._decorators import (  # noqa:F401
  File "C:\Users\CLIENTE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.properties import cache_readonly  # noqa:F401
  File "C:\Users\CLIENTE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\pandas\_libs\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.interval import Interval
  File "pandas\_libs\interval.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.interval
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.hashtable
  File "pandas\_libs\missing.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.missing
  File "C:\Users\CLIENTE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\pandas\_libs\tslibs\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion import (
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\timezones.pyx", line 14, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.timezones
  File "C:\Users\CLIENTE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\dateutil\tz\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .tz import *
  File "C:\Users\CLIENTE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\dateutil\tz\tz.py", line 19, in <module>
    import six
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'
```

I don't know what to do more to it finally work, can somebody help me with this?

Watching tutorials and reading other requests. I guess that I already found the correspouding versions using the codes from the videos.

Answer (score 0):

https://pypi.org/project/six/

Try to reinstall six module.

```
pip uninstall six
pip install six
```

Comment: It didn't work too